# Connect to MongoDB with authentication using Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to connect to MongoDB with user/password , this is what I did so far:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://${host}:27017/${db}", function(err, db) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log("successfully connected to the database");
  }else{
    console.log("Error on connecting... aborting and exiting");
    return console.dir(err);
    throw err;
   }

    db.authenticate('username', 'password', function(err, res) {
    console.log("reached here");                 

    });
});
```

Now I am trying to login inside the data base in order to be able to get inside Mongo Database's collections, how can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You are able to connect???

Comment: I am getting this message:

"successfully connected to the database"

but then I am disabled to do any manipulations...

Answer (score 0):

You can perform CURD operations like following:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://${host}:27017/${db}", function(err, db) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log("successfully connected to the database");
      //here you can perform operation
    var collection = db.collection('test');
    var doc1 = {'hello':'doc1'};
    var doc2 = {'hello':'doc2'};

    collection.insert(doc1);
  }else{
    console.log("Error on connecting... aborting and exiting");
    return console.dir(err);
    throw err;
   }

    db.authenticate('username', 'password', function(err, res) {
    console.log("reached here");                 

    });
});
```

Comment: I am getting this error afetr trying using 'find' method on my collections:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Comment: Seems like you are using find query of mongo outside mongo connect, where you don't have access to db or collection. You can make them global or make them available so as to run find query.

Comment: Manwal I am using this piece of code: 

var startId = 7882;
    var userCount = 100;
    var num = 190;
    var baseGeologOrig = db.geologs.find({user_id:279, created_at:{$gte:new ISODate("2015-01-31"), $lte:new ISODate("2015-02-02")}}).limit(1227);
    var baseGeolog = [];

i am getting the error on this line.